# Is there a way to programmatically see what solution an instance of Visual Studio has open (not as a plugin)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

Pretty straight-forward, but don't really know if it's even feasible.   Basically I'd like to have a winform (NOT a plugin to VS) that retrieves a list of of solutions that are currently loaded in open instances of Visual Studio.

**EDIT:** To clarify per comments below, I'm looking for the loaded solutions full path (e.g., `C:\projects\myrandomproject.sln`

Comment: Something sort of like TaskManager would display..? is this what you are talking about...?

Comment: Do you need the name of the solution, or anything more (like solution file location or other metadata)?

Comment: Does the title bar of the window contains the name of the solution?

Comment: What exactly do you need? What will you be doing with this information? You say not a plug-in, but could a plug-in be used as a helper, to store the current solution somewhere that your winforms app could read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate the running instances of Visual Studio through the running object table (ROT).  See [`IRunningObjectTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.irunningobjecttable.aspx) and [`GetRunningObjectTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684004.aspx).

You can then [get a reference to the DTE2 object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx) for each running instance [using the identifier from the ROT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228755.aspx).

Use [`DTE2.Solution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88y13x6f.aspx).  You can get its path from its [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.fullname.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

This is something just to get you started.. you will have to tweak it to which ever way you want..

4.If you just want to get the names of programs not the opened folders, then use the following code

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && p.ProcessName != "explorer")) 
{  
   Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName); 
} 
Console.ReadKey();
```

2.If you just want to get the process started by User not by the Windows then use the following code

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)) 
{  
   Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName); 
} 
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Looking for the file (solution) opened in the visual studio process, not the process itself.

Comment: no problem Chad.. @James response should the trick for you.. have you tried the C# code sample provide within the MSDN link on their site..?